# CSS - FULL website is moving when a:hover instead of 1 block

Tags: html, css

i am using some a:hover effect to give bigger bakground to connect 2 different block.

It should looks like: 
[image]

How it really looks:
1. First i try it clasicly with inline-block and when i go over a menu it just move rest of the part down, 2. my second try was to use position: absolute to disable this fact but with position absolute the looks is changing when resolution change or when the borowser window is smalelr.

My HTML:

```
 <div id="shopmenu">
    <ul>
    <li><span class="text"><a href="#">DISKUSNÍ FÓRUM </a></span><span class="horizontal-arrow"></span><span class="vertical-arrow"></span></li>
    <li><span class="text"><a href="#">KOMENTÁŘE </a></span><span class="horizontal-arrow"></span><span class="vertical-arrow"></span></li>
    <li><span class="text"><a href="#">ZÁZNAM CHATU </a></span><span class="horizontal-arrow"></span><span class="vertical-arrow"></span></li>
    <li><span class="text"><a href="#">UŽÍVATELÉ</a></span><span class="horizontal-arrow"></span><span class="vertical-arrow"></span></li>
 </div> 
 <div id="shop"></div>
```

My CSS:

```
#shop{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-image: url("images/under_news_bg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 121px;
    width: 987px;
    display:inline-block;
}

#shopmenu{
    color: #1a6eb6;
    position: absolute;
    display: inlne;
    right: 526px;
}

#shopmenu ul li{
    list-style-position: inside;    /* Bodka v novom riadku vo vnutry */
    list-style-type: none;          /* bez bodky */  
    background-image: url("images/shop_menu_bg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 31px;
    width: 187px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #1a6eb6;         
}
#shopmenu ul li:hover {
    background-image: url("images/shop_menu_bg_hover.png");
    width: 187px;
    height: 38px;             
}

#shopmenu ul li .text{
    color: #1a6eb6;
    display: inline-block;    /* aby sa dala rovnomerne posunut sipka a nie podla dlzky textu*/
    height: 31px;
    width:115px;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-left: 5px;         
}

#shopmenu ul li .horizontal-arrow{
    background-image: url("images/horizontal_arrow.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 19px;
    width: 14px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 45px;
    vertical-align: middle;       
} 

#shopmenu ul li:hover .horizontal-arrow{
    display:none;         
}

#shopmenu ul li .vertical-arrow{
    background-image: url("images/vertical_arrow.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    display:none;
    height: 12px;
    width: 19px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 45px;         
} 

#shopmenu ul li:hover .vertical-arrow{
    display: inline-block;             
}
```

Live preview with using position absolute can be find: http://funedit.com/andurit/newnew/
So how should i do that to connect that 2 parts when user :hover on menu? Can somebody help me with it?

Thanks for reading my post.

Comment: If you set the absolute positioned element's parent to be `relatively` position (`position: relative`), its parent will become its reference point and it will not break on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

Go with your solution #1. But set the height for the ul element

1. So remove position:absolute from #shopmenu
2. Add

   #shopmenu ul {
           height: 38px;
           margin-bottom: 0
       }
3. Set

   #shop {
           margin-top: 0;
       }